# UITableViewCell displaying incorrect data after assigning data to an UILabel

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uilabel

I encountered an interesting problem when coping with `UITableView`. I would be so much appreciated if anyone could point out where I made any mistakes.

So, the scenario is: I have a `NSArray` of `NSDictionaries`, and I am trying to make every row in the `UITableView` to display corresponding `NSDictionary`. Below is the code fragment of "`cellForRowAtIndexPath`" method:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    // configure custom cell
    static NSString *cellReuseId = @"cell";

    SearchTableViewCell *searchCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellReuseId forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (self.realData.count > 0) {
        self.tempDict = self.realData[indexPath.row];
        [searchCell initLabels:[self.tempDict valueForKey:@"psnname"] withDept:[self.tempDict valueForKey:@"deptname"] withPostion:[self.tempDict valueForKey:@"position"] withTel:[self.tempDict valueForKey:@"tel"] withFax:[self.tempDict valueForKey:@"fax"]];  
    } else {
        NSLog(@"no data");
    }
    return searchCell;
}
```

I made a custom `UITableViewCell`, and am trying to initialise five `UILabels` in a **custom** `UITableViewCell` by calling the "initLabels..." method. Here is the **"initLabels..."** method in the custom `UITableViewCell` `class`:

```
-(void) initLabels:(NSString *)psn withDept:(NSString *)dept withPostion:(NSString *)pos withTel:(NSString *)tell withFax:(NSString *)faxx{
    int tempWidth = self.frame.size.width/5;

    self.psnname = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.frame.origin.x + 10, self.frame.origin.y, tempWidth * 0.8, self.frame.size.height)];
    self.deptname = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.frame.origin.x + self.psnname.frame.size.width + 5, self.frame.origin.y , tempWidth * 1.1, self.frame.size.height)];
    self.position = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.deptname.frame.origin.x + self.deptname.frame.size.width + 5, self.frame.origin.y , tempWidth * 1.1, self.frame.size.height)];
    self.tel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.position.frame.origin.x + self.position.frame.size.width + 5, self.frame.origin.y , tempWidth * 0.7, self.frame.size.height)];
    self.fax = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.frame.size.width - tempWidth * 1.1, self.frame.origin.y , tempWidth, self.frame.size.height)];

    self.psnname.text = psn;
    self.deptname.text = dept;
    self.position.text = pos;
    self.tel.text = tell;
    self.fax.text = faxx;

    [self.contentView addSubview:self.psnname];
    [self.contentView addSubview:self.deptname];
    [self.contentView addSubview:self.position];
    [self.contentView addSubview:self.tel];
    [self.contentView addSubview:self.fax];
}
```

The problem is: when initialising those `UILabels` before assigning `UILabel's` with `NSString's`, the layout is in correct format BUT THE DISPLAYING DATA IS INCORRECT; while if assigning with NSString's before setting UILabel's frame, the data is **correctly displaying but the layout is out of format.**

What would be the potential reason that causes this to happen ??

Comment: Cells get reused. Think about what happens when you call `initLabels` over and over on the same cell instance.

Comment: BTW - it's a bad idea to name a non-initializer method with the prefix of `init`.

Comment: Can you post screenshot of your problem.

Answer (score 2):

You should separate the code that builds the view hierarchy of your custom table view cell from the code that populates it with data.

In the custom table view cell's `init` (or whatever is its initializer), add these:

```
self.psnname = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.frame.origin.x + 10, self.frame.origin.y, tempWidth * 0.8, self.frame.size.height)];
self.deptname = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.frame.origin.x + self.psnname.frame.size.width + 5, self.frame.origin.y , tempWidth * 1.1, self.frame.size.height)];
self.position = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.deptname.frame.origin.x + self.deptname.frame.size.width + 5, self.frame.origin.y , tempWidth * 1.1, self.frame.size.height)];
self.tel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.position.frame.origin.x + self.position.frame.size.width + 5, self.frame.origin.y , tempWidth * 0.7, self.frame.size.height)];
self.fax = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.frame.size.width - tempWidth * 1.1, self.frame.origin.y , tempWidth, self.frame.size.height)];

[self.contentView addSubview:self.psnname];
[self.contentView addSubview:self.deptname];
[self.contentView addSubview:self.position];
[self.contentView addSubview:self.tel];
[self.contentView addSubview:self.fax];
```

Then create a method in the table view cell subclass - something like the following - and call that method from your cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
- (void)populateWithPSN:(NSString *)psn dept:(NSString *)dept postion:(NSString *)pos tel:(NSString *)tell fax:(NSString *)fax
{
    self.psnname.text = psn;
    self.deptname.text = dept;
    self.position.text = pos;
    self.tel.text = tell;
    self.fax.text = faxx;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

another way is, just initialise the labels in the `init` method and set the frames of the labels in `layoutSubviews` method of custom cell, this method is called multiple times before cell is displayed, this is the best place to set the frames of the label, for example,

in your custom cell `.m` file

```
-(void)layoutSubviews
{
   [super layoutSubviews];
   self.psnname.frame = CGRectMake(self.frame.origin.x + 10, self.frame.origin.y, tempWidth * 0.8, self.frame.size.height);
   self.deptname.frame = CGRectMake(self.frame.origin.x + self.psnname.frame.size.width + 5, self.frame.origin.y , tempWidth * 1.1, self.frame.size.height);
   self.position.frame = CGRectMake(self.deptname.frame.origin.x + self.deptname.frame.size.width + 5, self.frame.origin.y , tempWidth * 1.1, self.frame.size.height);
   self.tel.frame = CGRectMake(self.position.frame.origin.x + self.position.frame.size.width + 5, self.frame.origin.y , tempWidth * 0.7, self.frame.size.height);
   self.fax.frame = CGRectMake(self.frame.size.width - tempWidth * 1.1, self.frame.origin.y , tempWidth, self.frame.size.height);
}
```

and for setting the data u can use the method of yours but for better readability u can modify it like

```
-(void)setLabels:(NSString *)psn withDept:(NSString *)dept withPostion:(NSString *)pos withTel:(NSString *)tell withFax:(NSString *)fax
```

and for cell creation method,

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

  // configure custom cell
  static NSString *cellReuseId = @"cell";

  SearchTableViewCell *searchCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellReuseId forIndexPath:indexPath];

  if (self.realData.count > 0) {
      self.tempDict = self.realData[indexPath.row];
     [searchCell setLabels:[self.tempDict valueForKey:@"psnname"] withDept:[self.tempDict valueForKey:@"deptname"] withPostion:[self.tempDict valueForKey:@"position"] withTel:[self.tempDict valueForKey:@"tel"] withFax:[self.tempDict valueForKey:@"fax"]];  
  } else {
       NSLog(@"no data");
  }
  return searchCell;
}
```